# Одновременное использование Telebot и Telepot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, gpio

С [python](/questions/tagged/python) я еще очень мало знаком. Собственно вопрос:

Пишу Telegram-бота. Цель - Бот должен спрашивать, какую команду я ему хочу дать и выполнять ее. Пока что дал ему 5 самых необходимых команд.

А именно: Есть *Raspberry Pi*, с него я запускаю сам скрипт, пока сделал это через Web-приложение, управляю подключенным к малине Led-диодом. Есть функции

- Включить зелёный свет
- Выключить зелёный свет
- Включить оранжевый свет
- Выключить оранжевый свет
- Функция перезагрузки Led-ов.

Через Web-приложение все работает. Использую библиотеку `Telepot`. Задача стоит в том, что бы избавиться от `Web` и перейти на управление с бота. Еще написал код, который работает с помощью бота, т.е. я могу с бота обрабатывать и исполнять эти функции. Хочу сделать так, чтобы не вводить все команды руками, а что бы были удобные кнопки.

Сейчас сделал так, что при запуске, он спрашивает "Что хочешь сделать?" и есть 5 кнопок с этими самыми функциями. Но все "крашится" как только нажимаю одну из кнопок. Кнопки тоже делать научился, используя библиотеку `Telebot`. Скажите, как можно их подружить? (Использовать одновременно)

Прилагаю код:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import time
import random
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime as dt
from functools import partial
import telebot
from telebot import types
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import telepot

TOKEN = 'Мой токен.'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


#LED
LedG=22
LedO=17

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(LedG, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LedO, GPIO.OUT)

def handle(msg):
        chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
        command = msg['text']

        print 'Got command: %s' % command

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(m):
        keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Turn On Green Led', 'Turn Off Green Led', 'Turn On Orange Led', 'Turn Off Orange Led', 'Reload']])
        msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'What will we do with the drunken sailor?', reply_markup=keyboard)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, name)

def name(m):
        if m.text == 'Turn On Green Led':
                print "Turn On Green Led"
                bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Turn On Green Led', parse_mode='Markdown')
                GPIO.output(LedG,1)
        elif m.text == 'Turn Off Green Led':
                print "Turn Off Green Led"
                bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Turn Off Green Led', parse_mode='Markdown')
                GPIO.output(LedG,0)
        elif m.text == 'Turn On Orange Led':
                print "Turn On Orange Led"
                bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Turn On Orange Led', parse_mode='Markdown')
                GPIO.output(LedO,1)
        elif m.text == 'Turn Off Orange Led':
                print "Turn Off Orange Led"
                bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Turn Off Orange Led', parse_mode='Markdown')
                GPIO.output(LedO,0)
        elif m.text ==  'Reload':
                print "RELOADING..."
                bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Led`s go to reload...', parse_mode='Markdown')
                GPIO.output(LedO,1)
                time.sleep(4)
                GPIO.output(LedO,0)

bot.polling()

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

Вот что происходит с момента запуска скрипта и до его окончания:

```js
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/socks.py:37: DependencyWarning: SOCKS support in urllib3 requires the installation of optional dependencies: specifically, PySocks.  For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contrib.html#socks-proxies
  DependencyWarning
telebottest.py:25: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(LedG, GPIO.OUT)
telebottest.py:26: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(LedO, GPIO.OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "telebottest.py", line 66, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 263, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 287, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 103, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 54, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
Exception in thread WorkerThread1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):Exception in thread WorkerThread2 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):Exception in thread PollingThread (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):root@raspberrypi:~/TelegramBot/telebottest# python telebottest.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/socks.py:37: DependencyWarning: SOCKS support in urllib3 requires the installation of optional dependencies: specifically, PySocks.  For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contrib.html#socks-proxies
  DependencyWarning
telebottest.py:25: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(LedG, GPIO.OUT)
telebottest.py:26: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(LedO, GPIO.OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "telebottest.py", line 66, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 263, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 287, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 103, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 54, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
Exception in thread WorkerThread1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):Exception in thread WorkerThread2 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_innerTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 57, in run
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Empty'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 61, in run

<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'exc_info'
```

Comment: Где исключение и traceback исключения?

Comment: @AndrioSkur, извините, не очень понимаю еще о чем вы говорите. Я видел что-то по поводу traceback когда крашится скрипт, но не смог найти нужной информации по этому поводу.

Comment: Это то, что нужно, добавьте в вопрос ошибки которые отображаются, когда скрипт "крашится"

Comment: Скрипт не падает. Если скрипт упал, то в консоле пишет что-то типа "Segmentation fault: ..". Скрипт валиться с исключением. От вас собственно нужен примерно такой текст (он появляеться в консоли перед окончанием работы) "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in
    int('qwerty')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'qwerty'" .

Comment: @AndrioSkur, Обновил вопрос.
P.S. Обновил код. Заменил bot.message_loop(handle) на bot.polling().
Так он хотя-бы запускается. Но при нажатии любой из кнопок в боте он завершает свою работу с ошибками.

Comment: @IgorSergeevich, Вопрос обновил.

Comment: 'telebottest.py:26: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use' Неправильно устанавливаете GPIO. Тут https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/ говорят что надо писать 'GPIO.setup([LedG, LedO], GPIO.OUT)'

Comment: @AndrioSkur, попробовал, тоже самое. Если делать через bot.message_loop(handler) - выдает ошибки среди которых есть ошибка о том что 'Telebot' не знает что такое message_loop.
Если делать через bot.polling(), все работает до нажатия любой из кнопок. Дальше те же ошибки :(

Comment: Хм. Попробуйте выкинуть весь код связаный с Raspberry Pi. А в функции name просто оставить 'print(m.text)'. Это упростит код, и ошибка виднее станет. (Выложите свою обновленную версию кода и новый traceback)

Comment: вне кода VPN пробывал? типа Windscribe?

Answer (score 1):

Я не эксперт, но кажется вам нужна 3 версия питона для написания бота

Comment: Не стоит в ответах писать «кажется». Ответы должны быть чёткими и однозначными без каких-либо догадок